# utf8 to ISO-8859-1 not converting some characters correctly through Curl

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have an application that is taking UTF8 encoded characters and needs to send them as part of xml through curl with ISO-8859-1 encoding.

This is my test code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=IS0-8859-1');

$message = '§ ° " @ # € % & / ( ) = + ` ´ ^ ¨ * - _ : . ; ,';

echo mb_convert_encoding($message, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

//build xml to post
$content =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <mobilectrl_sms>
        <header>
            <customer_id>'.CUSTOMER_ID.'</customer_id>
            <password>'.PASSWORD_ID.'</password>
        </header>
        <payload>
            <sms account="'.SHORT_CODE.'">
                <message><![CDATA['.mb_convert_encoding($message, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8').']]></message>
                <to_msisdn>+12345678900</to_msisdn>
            </sms>
        </payload>
    </mobilectrl_sms>';

$posturl = MT_URL;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml", "Content-length: ".strlen($content), "charset=ISO-8859-1"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

In the browser it almost works, I see § ° " @ # ? % & / ( ) = + ` ´ ^ ¨ * - _ : . ; ,

notice the Euro Sign €

But when it comes through as a text message I am seeing 
§ ? " @ # ? % & / ( ) = + ? ? ^ ? * - _ : . ; ,

I can't figure it out, I've tried utf8_decode also but that seems to make it worse.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no euro sign in ISO-8859-1, so it gets substituted with a question mark. There's nothing you can do about it, except choosing something else to substitute it with.

The same goes for the other characters that get converted to `?`s.

Comment: This is why ISO-8859-* is considered legacy and UTF-8/16 are considered to be the sensible and modern choices among the available standards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to look at converting those characters to something close.  Its for a sms application and apparently a lot of the carriers gsm still uses iso-8859 and this is in Europe!  I guess no one can text the Euro sign.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the multibyte extension doesn't know how to transliterate characters such as the Euro symbol, but `iconv()` does (example code from http://php.net/function.iconv#example-2228):

```
<?php
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Original : This is the Euro symbol '€'.
TRANSLIT : This is the Euro symbol 'EUR'.
IGNORE   : This is the Euro symbol ''.
Plain    :
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in .\iconv-example.php on line 7
This is the Euro symbol '
```

Note the use of `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)` which transliterates the '€' character into its Latin-1 "equivalent" of 'EUR'.

Answer (score 1):

Some SMS protocols accepts "%80" for the Euro sign. So you could try substituting the "€" with "%80" and URL-encode the rest of the string using ISO-8859-1. It worked for me for some SMS protocols.