# Which char is upsetting iconv?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a database of hundreds of thousands of sentences which I translate from utf-8 using iconv.

In two of the sentences, I get the following error:

```
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

I tried to check the input strings using the methods here: [How to detect malformed utf-8 string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723562/how-to-detect-malformed-utf-8-string-in-php)

```
$isUTF8 = mb_check_encoding($input, 'utf-8');
```

But, this function returns true (i.e. $input is a valid utf-8), and I still get those two error notices.

How can I detect which sentences are causing the problems?

Comment: How do you call `iconv`?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that your input is valid UTF-8, but that your target character encoding doesn't include one of the characters you're using. See [utf8 to ISO-8859-1 not converting some characters correctly through Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475179/utf8-to-iso-8859-1-not-converting-some-characters-correctly-through-curl) for an example.

If this is the case, you could perhaps use `//TRANSLIT`, if a substitution would be appropriate, or consider if it's possible to deliver content in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know which character is the problematic?

Comment: `iconv` will return [`FALSE` on failure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#refsect1-function.iconv-returnvalues). The logged notice should show up to the problematic character.